# IE browser Ajax call is taking 3 to 4 times more than Chrome

Tags: ajax, performance, google-chrome, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am facing a wired problem for IE browser Ajax call and was not able to found any solution for that problem. When I am making those calls in Chrome browser it is really fast but in the case of IE, it is taking almost 3 to 4 times more than Chrome. Please check the following screenshots for both Chrome and IE browsers. I also provide the timing information for certificationStatistics call, please let me know your thoughts if you have any idea about this issue.

IE Screenshots for Page Load

[image]

Chrome Screenshots for Page Load

[image]

IE Screenshots for CertificationStatistics API call

[image]

Chrome Screenshots for CertificationStatistics API call

[image]

NB: My frontend is developed with Angular and backend is node and node is calling java api.

Thanks
Ruzdi

Comment: is there any ajax call with async : false ??

Comment: No. It is completely asynchronous.